# Creating a vector text PDF with different fonts

Tags: c#, pdf, svg, vector, itext

I want to create a PDF from c# that has lines of text, but outlined and vectorized, so it can be used by a plotter.

I've looked at side-stepping to create a SVG first, then adding that to a PDF with iText in C# (asp net core).
However, i can't seem to find a solution to get font outlines as vectors from any given font.

Anyone got an idea on how to go about this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "vectorized text" here? Should there be no text drawing instructions but merely path drawing ones with stroke (not fill) operations? Or would it suffice to use the stroke text rendering mode?

Comment: It should be path drawing for stroke (not fill). Although i'm not sure what you mean with stroke text rendering mode. Perhaps that's a simplified method for achieving the same result?

Comment: *"i'm not sure what you mean with stroke text rendering mode."* - Have a look at [Table 104 — Text rendering modes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVNmB.png) of ISO 32000-2 (PDF specification), mode 1 "Stroke text". This would be the easiest way to achieve your goal but I don't know whether this is properly communicated to plotters.

Comment: I see what you mean, but no, it should be a vector path, as the plotter i intend to use is actually a drag knife cutter: http://wiki.fablab.is/wiki/Roland_GX-24_CAMM-1